# Publisher Macro run in all documents

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-publisher

I wrote a macro in Publisher and have added it to my Quick Access Bar. Unfortunately, the macro only runs in the document that created it. In all other documents, the button does nothing.

Is there a way to make the macro run in all Publisher documents? I know Excel macros have an option of where to store them (personal workbook, this workbook, et.c) which changes this behavior. Is there a similar option for Publisher?

Comment: Is there an *add-ins* button in the *developer* tab of the Ribbon? If so, the answer is "yes".

Comment: There is, but it accepts a .dll or a .exe. I'm assuming there's a simple way to compile a macro to a .dll?

Comment: Not really. You'll want a VSTO add-in, written in C# or VB.NET and referencing the Publisher API. Simple, *for some values of "simple"* ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It's not the ideal solution, but it should work. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no "Publisher add-in" document type, then you need to write a COM add-in in C# or VB.NET with Visual Studio (i.e. not in VBA).

[This article on MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/02/19/vsto-add-ins-for-access.aspx) explains how to go about making an add-in for Access, given:

> *VSTO supports add-ins for most Office applications that support IDTExtensibility2-based COM add-ins, that is: Excel, InfoPath, Outlook, PowerPoint, Project, Visio and Word, **but not for Access, FrontPage, Publisher or SharePoint Designer**.*

The process would be very similar for Publisher: reference the Primary Interop Assembly (PIA) to get a hold of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.Application` class, and you're pretty much all set - just design your Ribbon extensions, implement your functionality, compile, register, and you're up.